# Why won't data from a from save in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form where the user has to fill in all the fields. When all the fields are filled in and the submit buttons is pressed, i want the data to be stored in local storage and the user to be redirected to another page but for some reason this code wont work, any clue why?

***HTML5***

```
<form id="TheForm" action="SlutSidan.html" method="post">
                <div id="Row">
                    <input type="text" id="Name" placeholder="*Förnamn" required >
                    <input type="text" id="Surname" placeholder="*Efternamn" required >
                </div>      
                <div id="Row">
                    <input type="email" id="FirstEmail" placeholder="*e-postadress" autocomplete="on" required >
                    <input type="email" id="SecondEmail" placeholder="*Verifiera e-postadress" autocomplete="off" required >
                </div>
                <div id="Row">
                    <input type="text" id="Town" placeholder="*Ort" required >
                </div>  
                <div id="Row"> 
                    <input type="text" id="Address" placeholder="*Adress" required >
                </div>
                <div id="Row">
                    <input type="text" id="PostCode" placeholder="*Postnummer" required >
                </div>
                <div id="Row">
                    <input type="text" id="MobileNumber"  placeholder="*Mobilnummer" required >
                    <input type="text" id="TelephoneNumber" placeholder="Telefonnummer" >
                </div>  
                <textarea id="Comment" placeholder="Förslag på hur vi skulle kunna förbättra oss!"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" id="Submit" value="Skicka">    
            </form>
```

***Javascript***

```
var submit = function () {
    var name = document.getElementById('Name').value;
    var surname = document.getElementById('Surname').value;
    var firstemail = document.getElementById('FirstEmail').value;
    var getOrderNumber = localStorage.getItem('OrderNumberTemp');

    localStorage.setItem(getOrderNumber + ' Namn', name);
    localStorage.setItem(getOrderNumber + ' Efternamn', surname);
    localStorage.setItem(getOrderNumber + ' Email', firstemail);

    // Save all the other fields
};

window.onload = function () {
    var form = document.getElementById('TheForm');

    if (form.attachEvent) {
        form.attachEvent('Submit', submit);
    } else {
        form.addEventListener('Submit', submit);
    }
}
```

ps. the user does get redirected but nothing saves

Comment: The event name should be "submit", not "Submit".

Comment: ^^^ and for `attachEvent` it's `onsubmit`, and you're missing the last argument in `addEventListener`

Comment: thanks! why didnt i see that